# 'find' with wildcard

Tags: find, osx-yosemite

I am on OS/X yosemite. I have performed similar searches like the following many times: uncertain why it would not work here.

The search is:

```
$find . -name \*assembly\*.jar
```

It returns *nothing*.

Now, what *should* it return? Well let us remove the extension and re-run the search:

```
 $find . -name \*assembly\*
```

Well that returns a number of items - including the first one .. ends with **.jar** !

```
./mllib-tests/target/mllib-perf-tests-assembly.jar
./mllib-tests/target/streams/$global/assembly
./mllib-tests/target/streams/$global/assembly/$global/streams/assembly-inputs
./mllib-tests/target/streams/$global/assembly/$global/streams/assembly-outputs
./mllib-tests/target/streams/$global/assemblyOption
./mllib-tests/target/streams/$global/assemblyOption/$global/streams/assembly
./spark-tests/target/spark-perf-tests-assembly.jar
./spark-tests/target/streams/$global/assembly
./spark-tests/target/streams/$global/assembly/$global/streams/assembly-inputs
./spark-tests/target/streams/$global/assembly/$global/streams/assembly-outputs
./spark-tests/target/streams/$global/assemblyOption
./spark-tests/target/streams/$global/assemblyOption/$global/streams/assembly
```

So .. why is the first search failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK discovered the answer.  The

```
 \*
```

wildcard is *not*  a **zero or more** characters match. It is apparently a **one or more** characters match.

The following *does* work

```
$find . -name \*assembl\*.jar

./mllib-tests/target/mllib-perf-tests-assembly.jar
./spark-tests/target/spark-perf-tests-assembly.jar
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a non-breaking space or something else weird in filename `mllib-perf-tests-assembly.jar`? Otherwise, I think your implementation of `find` is broken.

Comment: Y for certain. The file is created by the  apache-spark build process used by many K's of developers.